# Scraping third table on webpage using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the third table from a webpage using beautiful soup but the only one I can extract is the first one:
Webpage: https://www.pro-football-reference.com/coaches/ReidAn0.htm#all_coaching_history

The code to load int the webpage is fine but there is where the issue is

Code:

```
table2=soup2.find('table', id="coaching_history")
```

That line isn't pulling any data. If i use the ID from the first table where id = "coaching_results" It works fine. It is just any table after that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to get that data:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url= 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/coaches/ReidAn0.htm#all_coaching_history'
wanted_table = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', ''))[2]
print(wanted_table)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    Year    Age Level   Employer    Role
0   1982    24  College (FBS)   Brigham Young   Graduate Assistant
1   1983    25  College (NCAA D-II) San Francisco State Offensive Coordinator/Offensive Line
2   1984    26  College (NCAA D-II) San Francisco State Offensive Coordinator/Offensive Line
3   1985    27  College (NCAA D-II) San Francisco State Offensive Coordinator/Offensive Line
4   1986    28  College (FCS)   Northern Arizona    Offensive Line
5   1987    29  College (FBS)   UTEP    Offensive Line
6   1988    30  College (FBS)   UTEP    Offensive Line
7   1989    31  College (FBS)   Missouri    Offensive Line
8   1990    32  College (FBS)   Missouri    Offensive Line
9   1991    33  College (FBS)   Missouri    Offensive Line
10  1992    34  NFL Green Bay Packers   Tight Ends/Asst. Offensive Line
11  1993    35  NFL Green Bay Packers   Tight Ends/Asst. Offensive Line
12  1994    36  NFL Green Bay Packers   Tight Ends/Asst. Offensive Line
13  1995    37  NFL Green Bay Packers   Tight Ends/Asst. Offensive Line
14  1996    38  NFL Green Bay Packers   Tight Ends/Asst. Offensive Line
15  1997    39  NFL Green Bay Packers   Quarterbacks
16  1998    40  NFL Green Bay Packers   Quarterbacks
17  1999    41  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
18  2000    42  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
19  2001    43  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
20  2002    44  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
21  2003    45  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
22  2004    46  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
23  2005    47  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
24  2006    48  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
25  2007    49  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
26  2008    50  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
27  2009    51  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
28  2010    52  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
29  2011    53  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
30  2012    54  NFL Philadelphia Eagles Head Coach
31  2013    55  NFL Kansas City Chiefs  Head Coach
32  2014    56  NFL Kansas City Chiefs  Head Coach
33  2015    57  NFL Kansas City Chiefs  Head Coach
34  2016    58  NFL Kansas City Chiefs  Head Coach
35  2017    59  NFL Kansas City Chiefs  Head Coach
36  2018    60  NFL Kansas City Chiefs  Head Coach
37  2019    61  NFL Kansas City Chiefs  Head Coach
38  2020    62  NFL Kansas City Chiefs  Head Coach
39  2021    63  NFL Kansas City Chiefs  Head Coach
40  2022    64  NFL Kansas City Chiefs  Head Coach
```